# PHP header ("Location: url.php") not working in godaddy

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, header

Good day. I have an issue regarding header ("Location: url.php"); in PHP. I wrote the code using Macromedia Dreamweaver MX 2004. All headers are working fine within localhost server but when uploaded to godaddy server, the redirection stucked in (login.php) page after login WITHOUT ERRORS. Here I provide the files (form and PHP files) and really hope all of you out there who have concerns and knowledge in this particular problem could help me. I dont really know what is the causes of the problem. Is it because of the code?

Or because of the SESSION?

Or because of the UTF-8 encoding?

I did change the properties of the page in Dreamweaver from Western Europian to UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM signature checked. Your help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

THIS IS IN (adminlogin.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conn.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))
{ header("Location: admin.php");} 
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Login</title>
<style>
#popUpYes
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: white;
}
#popUpYes:hover
{
    background-color: #D4A017;
} 
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<h2><font color=gold> Admin Login </font></h2>
<form method = "post" action = "login.php" >
<table>
<tr>
    <td> <font color=silver>Admin ID</font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" size=20 ><br></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td> <font color=silver>Password </font></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" size=20><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
<input type = "hidden" name = "submit">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "login" id="popUpYes" >
<input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "reset" id="popUpYes" >
</form>
<body background="c.png" bgproperties="fixed">
</body>
</html>
```

THIS IS IN (login.php)

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<?php
session_start();
include('conn.php');
if($_REQUEST['username']=="admin" && $_REQUEST['password']=="abc123")
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = "admin";
    $_SESSION['password'] = "abc123";
    header("Location:admin.php");
}
else{ ?> <script> 
    alert ( "Wrong combination of Username and Password. Please try again.");
    </script> <?php
    header("Location:adminlogin.php");
}
?>
<body background="c.png" bgproperties="fixed">
</body>
</html>
```

THIS IS IN (admin.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conn.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password']))
{ header("Location:adminlogin.php"); }
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a.button:hover
{
    background: #D4A017;
} 
</style>
<style> 
#pop
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: white;
}
#pop:hover
{
    background-color: #D4A017;
}  
</style>
<title>Admin Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "verification.php">
<br>
<h2><font color=gold>Admin Options: </h2><br></font>
<font color=white><b>
<input type ="radio" name="user" value="register">Click Here To Register An Agent<br>
<input type ="radio" name="user" value="regsales">Click Here To Create New Sales Record<br>
<input type ="radio" name="user" value="view">Click Here To View Agent Details and Sales<br>
<input type ="radio" name="user" value="edit">Click Here To Edit Agent Details and Sales<br></b>
<br><br>
<input type = "hidden" name = "verify"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="pop">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" id="pop"><br>
</font>
<body background="c.png" bgproperties="fixed"> 
<button><a class="button" href="logout.php" >Logout</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

THIS IS IN (conn.php)

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('domain', 'username', 'password','databaseName') or
 die(mysqli_error());

?>
```

Comment: header("Location:adminlogin.php")  wrong  header("Location:admin/login.php") write

Comment: Did you really need to post all that code? Could you please post it with proper formatting? Don't double-space it, and mark the entire code block as code, not each individual line.

Comment: hi @Vickey, im not sure i understand you. would that will cause it to heading to a (admin/login.php) instead of my desired page (adminlogin.php) ?

Comment: im sorry @Barmar. this is my first question asked. I will edit it later.

Comment: @Vickey Wrong.  You have no idea of the user's tree structure aside from what they've provided.

Comment: And don't forget to add `die` or `exit` after `header('Location:...')`

Comment: @DainisAbols, exit or die needed to add at all header(location:..) ?

Comment: @Aliff Yea, it is needed to add after **all** `header('Location:...')`, otherwise, the headers is set as the new page, but the script keeps executing the rest of the old page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell, the answer here is simple;

As stated on [the manual page for `header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you cannot send any content before the function call.  Delete your html above your php block, and move it somewhere else, and your code should work.

Further, as noted in the comments by @DainisAbols, you should use `die()` or [`exit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)(they both do the same thing) to prevent further script execution.

**Edit:**

In your login.php page, you have the following code:

```
<html>

<body> <!-- 
            Right here, you have content, above your header() call.  Because this
            content exists, the headers for the page have already been sent, and 
            thus, they cannot be sent again by header().  You need to move this
            block of html to after your php script, so that the first line in
            your file is the opening php tag: (<?php), with nothing before it
       -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<?php

session_start();
```

Comment: As an added note, the above in mind, I find it difficult to believe the function call worked on your local machine without problems.

Comment: thanks for the answer. so it is not a good practice to integrated php inside html codes? what do you mean move it somewhere else? i really in the state of confusion right now. :-|

Comment: i dont know why it works but i can assure you with pictures if you want the hard evidence @Daedalus :)

Comment: @Aliff Added what I hope to be a thorough explanation.

Comment: Finally! thank you so much @Daedalus. it worked. now i understand why my other header files are stucked too. :)

Comment: @Aliff Though I don't understand the un-accept.  Did I not meet what you require?

Comment: what do you mean un-accept? i did click on the "right" to an accepted answer and i find it useful @Daedalus because you helped me.

Comment: oh..only one answer is acceptable? haha now i get it.

Comment: @Aliff I see then; you can only accept one answer to a question; when you get enough reputation on this website, you gain the ability to upvote as well(15 I believe).

Comment: i just learned that Daedalus. is there any chance in this site for the user to become friends? like these days so-called social network features?

Comment: @Aliff There is not, SO isn't a social network, and things in that regard are frowned upon, though that doesn't stop one from trading contact information.  However, due to past circumstance, I do not wish to put my contact information out in the open at the moment.

Comment: i understand. by the way, theres still a problem. if i intentionally insert a wrong password, the header will not go back to the adminlogin.php page back.what shoud i do?

Comment: @Aliff Either delete or move the information(to the new page, maybe through `$_SESSION`) that you have at the start of the else.  The else should only contain header(), nothing in front of it(content sends headers).

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. Just use `ob_start();` on the top of script for multiple headers.

`ob_start()` function buffers all the server outputs to a string variable. That allows you to manipulate the HTTP headers anywhere in the code.

Comment: What does `ob_start();` do? Can you expand upon your answer?

Comment: @evolutionxbox This function is buffering all the server outputs to a string variable. That allows you to manipulate the HTTP headers anywhere in the code.

Comment: This is the true solution. My login script works on localhost but not on GoDaddy even though I am not sending any output before header. Strange but the good thing is your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not redirecting upon login because your headers have already been sent as a result of rendering html before attempting to send the location header in login.php. Move the markup at the top of the file into the else clause and that should do the trick (assuming there aren't any additional underlying issues).

Comment: thank you brandon. now i really understand the causes of this troublesome.